# Where can I find good voting data on US Congressional Districts?

Tags: united-states, election, voter-turnout, data-sources, voter-registration

For US Elections, I'm trying to find the Total Population, Voting Age Population, Registered Voters on Election Day, and the number of Ballots cast, for the years of 2020, 2018, 2016, and 2012, sorted by congressional districts. I've been able to locate some but not all of these fields, and I do understand that 2020 may contain incomplete data.

Comment: Which fields are you looking for?

Comment: https://ballotpedia.org/Main_Page  You can find everything here

Answer (score 1):

My advise is to contact the [Secretary of State for each of the states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_of_state_(U.S._state_government)) that you want data for, as well as what format you need it in. Be clear (and nice) as to who you are and why you are asking for the data. Right now they are busy with certifying the elections so this is a busy season for them, so being polite goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Walklists carry that data for free. If you go to [Walklists](https://walklists.com)

and click on buy voter data, you can check the answers to each of your question components. For more information how to do it properly, use this [guide](https://walklists.com/blog/post/how-to-buy-voter-list-for-the-state-of-california).